# pfSense + NAT and nginx - real IP not shown in logs

Tags: nginx, ip, nat, port-forwarding, pfsense

My current setup includes a pfSense firewall which port forwards public WAN traffic to a NAT internal IP.

Example:

- 104.12.134.12:80 (WAN IP) port forwards all traffic to 192.168.1.104:80

This is working as expected, traffic is forwarded on correctly. The issue I'm having is I see the local IP (i.e. pfSense router IP, in this case, 192.168.1.1) within Nginx logs.

I've searched and *lots* of articles suggest using real_ip module, and setting X-Forwarded-For header, but this doesn't work.

Notes:

- The IP of my router differs from the IPs I'm port forwarding (this is intentional).
- I don't own 104.12.134.12, this is just an example.

Comment: Show your iptables line which does nat.

Comment: Being pfSense, there's no iptables. If your router private IP shows in nginx logs, that's not a real-ip/proxying problem, but as @IporSircer suggests a NAT issue. How did you configure your port forwarding?

Comment: Is pFSense NAT the only thing in-between the WAN and server IP? Are you using the HAProxy module?

Comment: @Gmck pfSense NAT is the only thing between WAN and server IP, there's no proxy between those.

Comment: @SYN Port fowarding setup below.

Interface: WAN
Source address: *
Source ports: *
Dest. Addr: 104.12.134.12
Dest. Ports: 80/443
Nat IP: 192.168.1.100
NAT Ports: 80/443

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/VjDWy - I've blanked the real "Dest. Address" and "Description", but that's the setup. All rules are set to NAT Reflection enabled with NAT + Proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is now fixed.

My pfSense NAT outbound was configured incorrectly. I had both WAN and LAN mappings setup. Removing the LAN outbound mapping fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the load balancing capability of pfsense to do this (as described here : https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-use-pfsense-to-load-balance-your-web-servers) instead of a NATING Rule.

You can define only one loadbalancing pool with only one server in it.

Besides, it will allow you to add nginx servers later If you need it.